# popup to disappear when onmouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.infoLink').hover(function(){
            $('.shoutBox').hide();
            $(".shoutBox"+$(this).attr("id")+"").toggle();                          
            });

            $('.closeLink').click(function(){
            $(this).closest(".shoutBox").toggle();                   
            });
        });
```

I need to add a bit so that the popup will dissappear when visitors stop hovering over te popup link.

The popup link is a little "i" button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="infoLink rollover" id="box1"><img width="12" height="11" border="0" src="../path/to/randomimage.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
```

I tried to add:

```
$('.infolink').onMouseOut(function(close){
$('.shoutBox').close();
$(".shoutBox"+$(this).attr("id")+"").toggle();                            
});
```

something like that... But as you'd understand... this didn't work...

Anybody here that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover() event handler must have two functions as its argument. That is

```
$(".some-class").hover(function1(), function2());
```

What others have answered is correct. But if you find that syntax confusing you can try

```
function mouseIn(){
    $('.shoutBox').hide();
    $(".shoutBox" + this.id).show();                          
}

function mouseOut(){
    $(".shoutBox" + this.id).hide();                          
}
```

Now you can call the hover event handler.

```
$(".some-class").hover(mouseIn(), mouseOut());
```

Comment: Thanks a million as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event handler takes to callback methods, the first one is call on mouse enter and second one on mouse leave. if the second callback is not provided the first method is called on mouse leave also.

The problem with your callback is, you are hiding all `.shoutBox` before calling `.toggle()` which will cause the mouseleave handler to hide the current element first and since the toggle is called after that it will get displayed again

you need

```
$('.infoLink').hover(function(){
    $('.shoutBox').hide();
    $(".shoutBox" + this.id).show();                          
}, function(){
    $(".shoutBox" + this.id).hide();                          
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.infoLink').hover(function(){
            $('.shoutBox').hide();
            $(".shoutBox"+$(this).attr("id")+"").toggle();                          
            }, function() {
               $('.shoutBox').close();
               $(".shoutBox"+$(this).attr("id")+"").toggle();               
       });
```